# SQL Related - Code modification request and advice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

A newbie here! I have some SQL Code with many sub selects that act as rules. Now I have many nested WHERE Clauses using the LIKE operator, however I was wondering if there is a method to consolidate the code or consolidate the conditions.

```
SELECT   TOP 1 [ID]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_product_identifiers]
         WHERE [macro_products_id] = '3' -- Macro Prouduct Dropdown
         AND ISNULL([source_attribute_1],' ') LIKE                    

         (SELECT 
         [col1]-- First RULE value
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001' -- Current rule Template
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1') -- RULE sequence number (will be looped)
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_2],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col2]-- Second RULE value - etc.
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_3],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col3]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_4],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col4]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_5],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col5]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_6],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col6]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_7],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT DISTINCT
         [col7]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_8],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col8]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_9],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col9]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_10],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col10]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_11],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col11]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1')
AND ISNULL([source_attribute_12],' ') LIKE 
         (SELECT 
         [col12]
         FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
         WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001'
         AND [rule_sequence] = '1') AND [ID] -- Application Drop Down values below
      IN 
      (SELECT [ID]
      FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_product_identifiers]
      WHERE [macro_products_id] = '3' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_1],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_2],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_3],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_4],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_5],' ') LIKE '%' AND --  ETH-10GE (TEST VALUE)
      ISNULL([source_attribute_6],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_7],' ') LIKE 'BLTMMDCH' AND --  NYCMNY54 (TEST VALUE)
      ISNULL([source_attribute_8],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_9],' ') LIKE '%' AND --  AGSTMEST (TEST VALUE)
      ISNULL([source_attribute_10],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_11],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_12],' ') LIKE '%');--  KT (TEST VALUE)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Running code reviews / optimizations should go into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can be simplified

```
              SELECT TOP 1 [ID]
              FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_product_identifiers]
              CROSS APPLY (
                 SELECT [COL1], 
                        -- ... 
                        [COL12]
                 FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_rule_templates]
                 WHERE [template_name] = 'testADI001' -- Current rule Template
                    AND [rule_sequence] = '1') tpl
              WHERE [macro_products_id] = '3' -- Macro Prouduct Dropdown
              AND ISNULL([source_attribute_1],' ') LIKE  tpl.[COL1]
               -- ...   
              AND ISNULL([source_attribute_12],' ') LIKE  tpl.[COL12] 
              AND [ID] -- Application Drop Down values below
       IN 
      (SELECT [ID]
      FROM [forecast].[dbo].[forecast_tool_product_identifiers]
      WHERE [macro_products_id] = '3' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_1],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_2],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_3],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_4],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_5],' ') LIKE '%' AND --  ETH-10GE (TEST VALUE)
      ISNULL([source_attribute_6],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_7],' ') LIKE 'BLTMMDCH' AND --  NYCMNY54 (TEST VALUE)
      ISNULL([source_attribute_8],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_9],' ') LIKE '%' AND --  AGSTMEST (TEST VALUE)
      ISNULL([source_attribute_10],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_11],' ') LIKE '%' AND
      ISNULL([source_attribute_12],' ') LIKE '%');--  KT (TEST VALUE)
```

Comment: Wow! This really speeds up the process. A good result of query optimization! Thank you!